# Using IF Statement in SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

This is an excel expression "

```
IF(Prorated List>0,(Prorated List-OPE-Mul-Target),Discount*(Prorated List-OPE-Mul))
```

That I am trying to convert into a SQL code. But I do not know how to go about it. I would appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: Hello Ovie, Welcome to StackOverflow ? Can you explain what is 'Prorated' ? An Excel specific syntax ?

Answer (score 0):

In T-SQL, you can just replace `IF()` with `IIF()`, and your expression should work just fine. Note however, that T-SQL does not allow spaces in identifiers (such as column names): you need to quote them, that is put the name between square brackets (`[]`) - or better yet use identifiers without special characters.

In standard SQL, you would typically use a `case` expression:

```
case when prorated_list > 0
    then prorated_list - ope -mul - target
    else discount * (prorated_list - ope -mul - target)
end
```

You can factorize it a little:

```
(prorated_list - ope -mul - target) * (case when prorated_list > 0 then 1 else discount end)
```